# ETS2 DLCs not installing to Steam Folder?

Tags: steam, technical-issues, pc, euro-truck-simulator-2

I downloaded all the ETS2 DLC Map packs from the Euro Truck Simulator 2 site. The problem is now, when I run the installer and redirect the installer to my Steam directory where ETS2 is installed, it crashes and says that the folder is not valid. Why is this? None of my DLC map packs are installing.

The game is from Steam.

Many thanks

Comment: Where did you download them from? All I can find on the ETS2 site are links to buying steam keys or downloading the demo.

Comment: From Euro's Website itself. Nowhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just download them and install, as game has a non-steam version and the 2 versions dlc-s are not compatible with each other...(you cant just get the dlc for free) you need to find/obtain/buy dlc-s on steam and then steam will install them automaticly.

Comment: Dlc-s are avaliable for download from here: https://eurotrucksimulator2.com/download.php , but these are for non-steam version of the game and requires non-steam key

Answer (score 0):

If you bought the DLCs from Euros website then you will have got an email with the keys for said DLCs. You can use these keys just like any other game key and through the "Add product" option on the steam client add it to your account. Steam will automatically associate it with your copy of ETS2 and embed the files into your game files. If that doesn't work then install the DLCs to another file on you computer and then use the verify local files option in steam.

Your best bet is getting the keys for your DLC though.

[Source](https://itstillworks.com/12529792/how-to-install-dlc-with-steam)